Is it possible to find the actual dimensions of the Radial Drive Shaft and Bevel Gear of the CFM56-7B?
I am trying to draw to make a 3d model of the RDS in the CFM56-7B and I wasn't able to find the dimensions anywhere on the internet. And, what are the materials used to make them?

If you don't need engineering accuracy, you can start from this 2D blueprint, and knowing some dimensions, find the other.
If have done that to create small 3D models, and for the CFM56-7B, the measured result is this one (in Blender, not really a CAD application):

I think the scale is correct (the fan diameter is 61 in, 1.55 m). You can use the grid to evaluate other dimensions, the step is 1 cm. The shaft in context:

The inner and outer RDS are hollow and made of steel alloy.

Thank you for the answer. One more question, probably stupid but what's the diameter of the shaft?

@Nighthawk25, here are some more measurements (the golden shaft is N1 for reference), remember they are not more precise than the 2D blueprint used to model the parts.
